# Multithreaded ray tracing

Tags: c, multithreading, graphics, pthreads, raytracing

I want to implement multithreaded ray tracer program. I am using glut. How can I implement multithreading in my program? I mean I am not able to get the structure of program while using glut.

Answer (score 0):

This is one major issue with (standard) glut.

With glut (when I actually happen to still use it though), my usual approach is to have some global object representing my application state/context and then I really just dispatch the glut callbacks to some methods.

**However** I would advise you to use a different toolkit, [GLFW](http://glfw.org/) is a viable **and** more powerful alternative.

From there on, you have your app context and can start to implement something meaningful on top of it ;).